How to make minimum propagation delay pulse stretcher?
I want to stretch a pulse of 100mV and 1ns width to 3.3V and 10ns width with minimum propagation delay. I found a pulse stretcher in Linear's Application Note 87 document(https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an87f.pdf), but the LT1720 used here has a propagation delay of 4.5ns. Is it possible for me to perform this operation with a maximum delay of 1ns? Is there any suggestion that can reach these values without using comparator
I looked into comparators, but the ones with the lowest propagation delay have LVDS, ECL, or PECL outputs. I couldn't imagine how to set up this circuit with these comparators either

The best I obtained was some ~ 2ns propagation delay (modifying C and 24 Ohm).

What is the amplitude and width of the original pulse, and what is the width of the stretched pulse? Please add these details by editing the question, and then flag this comment as “no longer needed”.

The general approach for “zero” delay is: pass the leading edge of the original pulse unchanged to the load, and use it to trigger a switch and a mono stable. The switch disconnects the incoming pulse while it’s still active, and connects the output of the monostable. When the monostable times out, the switch connects the pulse input again to the output. There are details in how to make this work, of course. I’ll extend this answer sometime later.

I would be very pleased if you could explain the details.

If you have time could you please extend the details.

Although the propagation delay is specified at 4.5 ns, we can obtain a reduced delay of 2.5 ns with this modified circuit.
Don't know the "initial" conditions of the input signal. Verified. No change.


I've used for similar puprposes following setup:
MAX9600/96001 or similar comparator with PECL output to detect rising edge of pulse
MC100EP31 or similar flip flop to extend pulse width. Then route delayed flip flop output back to its reset input and you have fast "pulse stretcher".
Delay can be realised in multiple ways.
A) you can low pass (by RC filter) flip flop output to second comparator (you have two, or four in MAX9600/9601/9602). Choose second threshold to set delay (simply by potentiometer).
B) Take some PECL delay line, like 100EP195, 100EP196, SY89295, SY89296, NB6L295
